# Can't change product description in specific store view

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, store-view

I'm using Magento 2.3.
I have created some store View
[image]

But in my product i can't change short description and description, all the other field change without any problem, i can only change it in "default".
For example in this product, the Description field stay locked, and tinyMCE also. I have try also in HTML mode, but i can't change anything.

[image]

Thank for any help or idea.

Ben

Update

In each specific store view, the text area are disabled, but i don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: I've checked; I can edit product descriptions in default and store view. Have you tried another browser already? Maybe a browser plugin blocks the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no change in chrome, Firefox or Safari

Comment: Are there any console errors in your browser?

Comment: Thanks for your help, no error in console, sadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This correct the problem :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba4bd08cde8d6639dfe084f1d9ea4e488e11f8e6

Thanks for your help guys